# SSRS subreport blank space issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 definition RDL (converted from a working 2005 definition RDL).

A subreport is attached into the detail group in the tablix.

When trying to render it, it provides weird behavior:

By rendering the report with different dataset (number of records),

sometimes it rendered properly as:

```
Group A Header 
Group B Header & content
Group Detail - subreport
Group B Footer & content
Group A Footer
```

There is no blank space and pagebreak. Everything is fine

but sometimes it rendered as below

```
Group A Header
---blank space until next page
Group B Header & content
---blank space until next page
Group Detail & subreport
Group B Footer 
Group A Footer
```

The blank space is unexpected. It looks like the height of subreport causing these blank space. Is there anything to do which can prevent subreport creating these unexpected blank space?

----- Some attempted solution------
Consume white space on the report properties

Confirmed no page break

Subreport keep together is set to false (i tried set all KeepTogether to false in both main and subreport)

Subreport width set to thin (from 27cm to 5cm, most tablix cell removed, except the cell which caused the particular height of the subreport, as mentioned, this subreport height is dynamic, based on the number of records, for example when the number of records cause the subreport height to particular height (for example 29cm), the unwanted blank space would be occurred, the weird thing is that these blank space can be removed if I change the height of the tablix to more or less than 29cm, but this is not the solution, as number of records eventually cause the subreport to 29cm again, and blank space occurred to other dataset, in fact it is not recommended to change static tablix row height),

Subreport interactive height to 0 (just try anything when there is no solution at all)

Thus these blank space is pretty sure not caused by the width of subreport, but the height of subreport (not over, but close to a particular height)

The sql server is 2012, and the rdl report definition is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition"

Thanks.

Comment: what if you put a rectangle in the subreport, and then put your tablix inside the rectangle?

Comment: no, i tried removed everything from the subreport, and only put an rectangle into it with certain height. during the report rendering, blank space still appeared.